# How do I do if statements in Cucumber scenarios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

My app has permissions, and certain tests need to not be run when a particular permission is on, and some tests need to be run when that same permission is on.

Is there a way to do this? or do I need to use a different framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of excluding 'tests' in Cucumber is to add a tag to them to identify them, then when invoking Cucumber you specify which tags to include/exclude.  In your example, you could tag a specific scenario:

```
@needs_permission
Scenario: View users billing information
```

Or tag the whole feature:

```
@needs_permission
Feature: Administrative area
    Scenario: View users billing information
```

Or tag certain examples in a scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Visit a page
    Given I visit "<page>"

Examples: Don't need permission
    | page    |
    | index   |
    | sitemap |

@needs_permission
Examples: Do need permission
    | page  |
    | admin |
```

Now, when you run Cucumber, you can exclude those tags if necessary:

When the permission is on and you want to run all tests:

```
cucumber .
```

When the permission is off and you want to exclude the tests that need it:

```
cucumber . -t ~@needs_permission
```

An alternative which I have used with mixed results, if you really don't know ahead of time, is to mark a step as `pending` if it doesn't apply given the current scenario, e.g.

```
Given /^I visit some page which needs permission$/ do
    pending "Permissions aren't enabled - skipping" unless permissions_enabled?
end
```

This will mark the step as 'pending' which really means 'not fully implemented', which isn't ideal, especially if you have many such steps - it can be difficult to ensure that other unimplemented steps don't accidentally creep in and get hidden by all the ones you've deliberately marked as such.

Answer (score 1):

We get a similar instance of this a lot, we have 2 solutions, 
either tags as suggested, or 
create different scenarios for different permission types:

```
Given i log in as a moderator 
and there is a new post
when i view the post
Then i should see a delete button  

Given i log in as a normal user 
and there is a new post
when i view the post
Then i should not see a delete button
```

Answer (score 0):

May be possible using tags. Difficult to say without more detail.